React native display video from backend sending it as blob
I'm using expo react native and i'm trying to display a video coming via my backend via an url, the url on any web browser opens and start playing directly, but it's not the case on react native even when using .blob() on response object as follow:
//fetch logic
const data = await response.blob(); 
url = URL.createObjectURL(
return url;

//videoContent will receive the url i'm returning 
<VideoPlayer
                    videoProps={{
                    shouldPlay: true,
                    resizeMode: ResizeMode.CONTAIN,
                    source: {
                      uri:videoContent,
                      // uri: 'https://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4'  
                    }
                    }}
                />

The problem does not come from VideoPlayer, because I have tried random videos using their urls and everything worked fine.

Can you update the location on tap? and then use the api response after?
